# How to set Desktops.exe as an autorun program using cmd

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista

The scenario goes like this. A computer is infected w/ a ransomware and you can't do anything else and all you have is a command prompt window. Now how do you set Desktops.exe as an autorun program so that you'll be able to trigger it using a keyboard combination to launch a virtual desktop where you can do the troubleshooting?

Answer (score 5):

First: You are doing it backwards.
First priority is to CLEAN the machine.
And the only certain way to do that is to boot from a rescue-medium and scan/clean the machine from there.

But sometimes you don't have a choice. 
Example: When you have a machine that uses some form of disk-encryption so you can't get at the harddisk when booted from other media.

In that case boot it in "Safe mode with command prompt".
Then run regedit (there is a GUI, just not an Explorer shell running at that time).
In regedit go to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.
Add you autorun program as extra entry in that key.
Alternatively you can use the REG.EXE command to do the same from the commandline.

(It is a good idea to remove ALL other entries from the Run key while you are at it. One of them might be part of the malware. You can use the export function of Regedit to temporarily save them in a file.)

An alternative to this is to change the logon shell from explorer.exe to a filemanager (like TotalCommander or DirOpus).
Sometimes adding autorun entries doesn't work, but using an alternative shell does.
That is in the key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon. You will have to change the value of the "Shell" entry for that (you can use a full path to the executable).

**Please note** that adding an extra program, that relies on keyboard input while the malware is active, may NOT work. The malware can easily hijack any keyboard input thereby preventing your program to activate.

Comment: In this case there is the destruction of natural environment for the virus without its analysis and the possible launch of its truncated version. After that diagnosis and finding the parts of the virus is much more complicated. What usually leads to: 1. incomplete removal of pieces of malicious software. 2. to missing gaps and vulnerabilities creating viral environment. 3. the emergence of new infections on the basis of the remaining vulnerabilities OS

Answer (score 0):

Open file:

```
openfiles /Query /FO:csv | more
```

View NetBIOS network open files:

```
net files
```

Process commandline, caption, Pid:

```
Wmic process get CommandLine, name, ProcessId | more
```

Process path, caption, Pid:

```
Wmic process get ExecutablePath, name, ProcessId | more
```

Network active process:

```
netstat -aon | findstr [1-9]\. | more
```

Network active process with name:

```
netstat -baon | more
```

Job list:

```
wmic job list STATUS
```

Autorun list:

```
wmic startup list full | more
```

View import dll module (Embarcadero or Borland version):

```
tdump -w hal*.dll | find "Imports from "
```

Remove all permissions and permits the user to disable all:

```
cacls <filename> /T /C /P %username%:N
```

Terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it:

```
taskkill /PID <pid1> /PID  <pid2>  /PID  <pid3>  /T
```

Comment: And how is this relevant to the question ? This a list of command-line troubleshooting commands, but the output of these commands can NOT be trusted on a compromised machine.

Comment: @Tonny Well then I suggest to hide in a bunker where the steel should check BIOS motherboard, video,  network cards ... and most importantly IBM PC architecture is very far from the word "security" ... 

Clean operating system, clean the computer does not help us much.

Why? Example - boot virus on your hard disk. You will transfer it to another machine and will generate infection? Or in the case of a virus that infects BIOS put clean hdd and also produce infection carrier?

Let's think in terms of conditions.

Comment: You completely missed the point: You didn't answer the question AT ALL. The only proper solution is to clean from trusted media, or failing that, attempt to bypass the virus (what this question is about) so an attempt to manual cleaning can be made. Your commands are useful for diagnosis, but do NOT solve anything and do not provide an answer to the question. And whether they can be trusted to tell you the truth on an infected machine is dubious.

Comment: @Tonny Quote the author: `you can't do anything else and all you have is a command prompt window` Нere does not say what you want to use. Here you only have a command line on the infected system and you act through it.